# Graphics : VESA: MCP61 - mcp61-80

Tags: graphics

What does the graphics : Graphics : VESA: MCP61 - mcp61-80      says
    please explain it in detail

i am asking this because my PC gets stucked when i norrmally log into it.
 If i open it in recovery mode from the grub menu it is working very slow   and the failsafex mode is showing cannot detect your screen, graphics and devices.I guess it might be the problem of drivers but not know how to solve it.The problem might also be due to some other things unaware of.

really need help guys..

thanks in advance.